# Taxonomy vocabulary not showing up as existing field in new content type

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 taxonomy vocabularies which I want to reference in new content types but I cannot see them under "add existing fields" when creating a new content type. Also tried referencing one taxonomy vocabulary from another and couldn't.

Saw this [post on drupal forum](https://www.drupal.org/node/2293191) and followed the suggestion of changing admin theme but it didn't work for me.

BTW, I'm using Marinelli theme.

Kind regards,

Jio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use taxonomy with your content nodes, you have to add fields to your content types that allow you to assign taxonomy terms.
To add a field for your taxonomy to a content type:

1. Go to **Structure > Content types**.
2. Find the listing for the content type you want to modify, and then
   click its **manage fields** link.
3. In the Add new field section, enter text for the **Label** and **Name**
   columns.
4. In the **Field type** column, select **Term reference** from the drop-down
   menu.
5. In the **Widget** column, use the drop-down menu to select from the
   following widgets:

   ```
     Check boxes/radio buttons - The taxonomy terms are listed in a check box on the content creation page for this content type.
     Select list - A list of the taxonomy terms are displayed on the creation page for this content type.
     Autocomplete term widget (tagging) - A text box is added to the content creation page for this content creation page.
   ```

   Selected or entered taxonomy terms are assigned to the content node when the node is saved or published.
6. Click **Save**.
7. In the **Vocabulary** drop-down menu, select the vocabulary you want to
   use with this content type.
8. Click **Save settings**.

A taxonomy term field is added to your content type, using the label you chose. When you create content of this type, you will now find a field on the creation and edit forms that allows you to assign taxonomy terms to the content node.

Thank you.